# How do I parametrise this expression

Tags: functions

[image: equation]

I have no idea how to deal with the Mins when attempting to parametrise this. How do I do it?

Comment: This inequality will give a region in the plane, not a curve. Parameterization relates to a curve. How can you parameterize a region?

Comment: @RoryDaulton, you can parameterize some regions with two parameters.

Comment: I don't know. It's from an old exam. I thought it was odd that they want a region parametrised, too. I would assume it's OK to just parametrise the curve.

Comment: I would guess set $x-2=4cos(\theta)$, $y-3=4sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Min(a,Min(b,c))$ is the minimum of $a$, $b$, and $c$. So the equation
$$Min(a,Min(b,c)) \ge 0$$ is the same as
$$a \ge 0 \text{ and }b \ge 0 \text{ and } c \ge 0$$
So in your case you want the intersection of the three regions
$$16-(x-2)^2-(y-3)^2 \ge 0$$
$$x-y+1 \ge 0$$
$$3-y \ge 0$$

This is the intersection of a circular region with two half-planes. The corner of the half planes is $(2,3)$ which is also the center of the circle, so the region is a sector of a circle.

[image]

Therefore we could parameterize by
$$x=2+r \cos \theta$$
$$y=3+r \sin \theta$$

where $0 \le r \le 4$ and $-\frac {3\pi}4 \le \theta \le 0$. Other parameterizations are possible, of course.